# Elasticsearch - forcibly kill shard

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, sharding

I need to test an Elasticsearch 5 app when 1 or more shards are down. Is there any way to forcibly kill a shard? (Using Java, or curl or Sense?)

Comment: There is a way to disable shard allocation. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: If I disable shard allocation, I will not be able to run a search at all, right? I want to run a search, but during that process, need to bring down a shard.

Comment: If you are on a single node, you only have primary shards assigned. It makes no sense to kill a primary shard, that would mean you are missing some of your data and your cluster would be corrupted. it makes even less sense for ES to provide such a feature. Why do you want to test that?

Comment: Well I want to test exception handling.

Comment: A useful discussion  [Trigger a red cluster state?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/trigger-a-red-cluster-state/9786) suggests creating an index with unsatisfied allocation requirements to put the cluster on red state

Comment: e.g. `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/bad-index -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"settings":{"index.routing.allocation.include._id":"does not exist"}}'`

Comment: And when you are done with your testing, simply delete the index and your
cluster will return back to a green state: `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/bad-index`

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for that — you'll have to wait for the self-destruct API for another version ;-).

But it sounds like a common scenario: Have a multi-node cluster (3 is normally the minimum for a production setup) and just kill one node. Could be a graceful shutdown, a kill 9, stopping the network interface,... Then you can see how Elasticsearch behaves and recovers under such scenarios.

Comment: Hmm, but elasticsearch has just a single process running(if you do a ps -ef | grep elastic*). So how could I kill just one node?

Comment: On the test level we are doing similar things (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/test/framework/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/shard/IndexShardTestCase.java). But I don't understand what you are trying to test here. How would just one (or a few) shards be affected and not an entire node. And if you want high availability you'll need 3 nodes at least anyway.